# Percentage calculation error

Tags: javascript, html, percentage

I am trying to calculate percentage of a number (taken from one text field) and set the calculated value to another form field. For this I have tried the below code but I am observing a mismatch in the key event/decimal places that js is detecting.

For example if I provide 100 in first input field (to calculate the percentage of 1.75), based on my js code I expect 1.75 but in the second text field it is coming as 0.175.
I know this a very simple calculation but I am unable to solve this.

```js
var reFee = document.getElementById("Estimated Referral Fee");
var LnAmt = document.getElementById("Loan Amount");
reFee.disabled = true;

LnAmt.onkeydown =
  function isNumber(evt) {

    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
      return false;
    }
    calcPer(LnAmt.value);
  }

function calcPer(amtval) {
  var pernum = 1.75;
  reFee.value = (pernum / 100) * amtval;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Loan Amount</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input id="Loan Amount" placeholder="Provide Loan Amount" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Provide Loan Amount" required="required" class="form-control" name="Loan Amount" type="text" value="">
    <span class="help-block"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Estimated Referral Fee</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input id="Estimated Referral Fee" placeholder="Your referral fee" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Your referral fee" required="required" class="form-control" name="Estimated Referral Fee" type="text" value="" disabled="">
    <span class="help-block"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's because you're using `onkeydown`, which gives you the value before you pressed the key, so upon pressing the second `0`, it's receiving the first characters `10`. Try it with `onkeyup` or `oninput` and you'll see it work.

Comment: @squint: yes `onkeyup` worked for me :) thanks

Comment: I have an observation here. if I try with `onkeyup` though I am getting the expected value but the function `isNumber()` added for number only input validation is failing

Comment: Oh, didn't notice the check. I think you may need `onkeypress` to test the individual character. Then if you still only get the first 2 in the `.value`, you'd need to add the most recent character manually.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var reFee = document.getElementById("Estimated Referral Fee");
var LnAmt = document.getElementById("Loan Amount");
reFee.disabled = true;

LnAmt.onkeyup =
  function isNumber(evt) {

    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
      return false;
    }
    calcPer(LnAmt.value);
  }

function calcPer(amtval) {
  var pernum = 1.75;
  reFee.value = (pernum / 100) * amtval;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Loan Amount</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input id="Loan Amount" placeholder="Provide Loan Amount" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Provide Loan Amount" required="required" class="form-control" name="Loan Amount" type="text" value="">
    <span class="help-block"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Estimated Referral Fee</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input id="Estimated Referral Fee" placeholder="Your referral fee" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Your referral fee" required="required" class="form-control" name="Estimated Referral Fee" type="text" value="" disabled="">
    <span class="help-block"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```